# ASP.NET MVC with google analytics tacking root url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-analytics

I have an ASP.NET MVC site and my google analytics code is the example code cut/pasted into my layout page.  This is how it records root requests:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to get it to record only the `/` as the root url?  For reference here is my analytics code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    try {
        var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("my code");
        pageTracker._trackPageview();
    } catch (err) { }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `_trackPageview` value to the page you want to log the metrics under, e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    try {
        var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("my code");
        pageTracker._trackPageview("/");
    } catch (err) { }
</script>
```

Comment: Does this mean I have to manually set it on every page?  Because if that's the case I think I can handle this one oddity to correct identify all of my other stats.

Comment: I use the same code on my master page and pass in the page to represent as a property of the Model. So the code ends up looking like `pageTracker._trackPageview("<%= Model.TrackingPage %>");`

Comment: That's a good way of doing it, luckily I already have a model for my layout or that would be a ton of work though. :)  Before I accept I'm going to try it out however.